# How do I know which button is clicked when the bootstrap modal closes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my modal html code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="delete-file-modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="delete_file_form">

                <div class="modal-body">
                    Are you sure you want to delete this file?  
                </div>  

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-danger" name="in_confirm_insert" id="confirm-delete-button">Delete</button>
                    <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" name="in_confirm_insert" id="cancel-delete-button">Cancel</button>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is my javascript code:

```
$('#delete-file-modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {

    var delete_button = $(e.target).is("#confirm-delete-button");

    if(delete_button === true) {
        //delete file
        alert("file deleted.");
    } else {
        alert("delete failed.");
    };
});
```

I need to be able to check if the delete button is clicked when the delete-file-modal is closed. Is there something else missing in my javascript code?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

#### Option #1

Within the `hidden.bs.modal` event listener, `event.target` refers to the modal element that is hidden, *not* the clicked element that triggered the event.

If you want to determine which button triggered the modal to close, one option is to add event listeners to the button elements inside of the modal. Then inside of the button event listener you could listen to the `hidden.bs.modal` event on the parent `#modal` element in order to determine if the modal was closed. Since the `hidden.bs.modal` event listener is inside of the button `click` event listener, you still have a reference to the element that triggered the `click` event.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/gpoq8e9b/)

```
$('#delete-file-modal .modal-footer button').on('click', function(event) {
  var $button = $(event.target); // The clicked button

  $(this).closest('.modal').one('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    // Fire if the button element 
    console.log('The button that closed the modal is: ', $button);
  });
});
```

It's also worth mentioning that the [`.one()` method](http://api.jquery.com/one/) will only fire the event once each time it is attached (which is exactly what we want). Otherwise, if you used `.on()` or `.click()` to attach the event, then the event could fire multiple times since it is reattached each time the `click` event listener is fired.

---

#### Option #2

According to the relevant [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals), the `show.bs.modal`/`shown.bs.modal` events have a `relatedTarget` property attached to the event.

> If caused by a click, the clicked element is available as the `relatedTarget` property of the event.

Thus, you can determine the element that triggered the modal to open event by accessing `event.relatedTarget` inside of the modal show event listener:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/gx97spa1/)

```
$('#delete-file-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    console.log(event.relatedTarget);
});
```

Keep in mind that the `relatedTarget` property is only associated with the modal show events. It would be nice if they had a property like that associated with the `hide.bs.modal`/`hidden.bs.modal` events. As of writing this, there currently *isn't*.

---

#### Option #3

As Andrew pointed out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28270333/how-do-i-know-which-button-is-click-when-bootstrap-modal-closes/28270395?noredirect=1#comment71408704_28270395) below this answer, you can also check to see which element on the page has focus by accessing [`document.activeElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement).

In the snippet below, an event listener is attached to the modal element for the show and hide events. When the event is triggered, a check is made to see if the currently focused on element has a `[data-toggle]` or `[data-dismiss]` attribute (which implies that it did in fact trigger the event).

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/L9xo0vc9/)

```
$('#delete-file-modal').on('hide.bs.modal show.bs.modal', function(event) {
  var $activeElement = $(document.activeElement);
  
  if ($activeElement.is('[data-toggle], [data-dismiss]')) {
    console.log($activeElement);
  }
});
```

If you are listening to both show/hide events, like in the example above, and you want to differentiate between the events, you could check `event.type`:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/z4gwcw0u/)

```
$('#delete-file-modal').on('hide.bs.modal show.bs.modal', function(event) {
  var $activeElement = $(document.activeElement);
  
  if ($activeElement.is('[data-toggle], [data-dismiss]')) {
    if (event.type === 'hide') {
      // Do something with the button that closed the modal
      console.log('The button that closed the modal is: ', $activeElement);
    }
    
    if (event.type === 'show') {
      // Do something with the button that opened the modal
      console.log('The button that opened the modal is: ', $activeElement);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the examples it worked perfectly. But I need to check if the button inside the modal is clicked after the modal is closed. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: I'm using jQuery 3 and `e.relatedTarget` shows undefined

Comment: It's also showing undefined in jQuery2.11 *** Disregard ***   Was focusing on the modal event and not the button event...

Comment: @DarkTurtle - I just tested it with jQuery v3.1 and [it worked here](http://jsfiddle.net/99d8sr7f/). If you provide an example of it not working, then I can take a look.

Comment: This works too:  
    $('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var tmpid = $(document.activeElement).attr('id');
        alert(tmpid);
    });
It won't get the 'X' on the modal unless you id it....

Comment: Option #3 is nice, though it has one drawback: calling `.hide()` manually will be also considered as pressing escape (as document.activeElement is set to body).

Comment: The fiddles in Option #3 do not show an alert in Firefox 57 or Safari 10.1.2. Is this obsolete? It works in Chrome though.

Comment: @robsch Option #3 doesn't appear to work in Safari or Firefox for Mac (possibly a version issue rather than a platform one): the modal itself is the active element when a button is clicked, not the button itself.

Answer (score 9):

This works too:

```
$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) { 
var tmpid = $(document.activeElement).attr('id'); alert(tmpid); 
});
```

It won't get the id of the 'X' on the modal unless you id it. Will return the id of the element which triggers the closing of the modal....

Comment: You might also want to do a check against `$(document.activeElement).hasClass('btn')` to ensure it was a button push and not something else. Here's why I had to do it that way. I was using the same Are Your Sure? dialog for an enrollment and a cancellation prompt. So, I had the same `id` on the buttons shown. So, I had to check for the `.text()` property of the button and then use `.indexOf()`. But if someone clicked the background or hit escape, my if/then condition would show the wrong result. That's why I now check with `.hasClass('btn')`.

Comment: Concise and clear. I love it! Note, this will work on `hide.bs.modal` but not `hidden.bs.modal`. The latter will always show the active element as `body`, which makes sense since the modal has already been removed from the DOM.

Comment: This one is the best! It will not only solve the issue that I have currently but will define my future use of the bootstrap modal.

Comment: as of December 2022 this doesn't seem to work in Safari.  Works in Chrome and Firefox though.

Answer (score 2):

To extend @JoshCrozier's answer:

> It would be nice if they had a property like that associated with the hide.bs.modal/hidden.bs.modal events. As of writing this, there currently isn't

---

This will emulate a similar behaviour, that attaches the clicked button as relatedTarget for later listeners:

```
$( '.modal-footer .btn[data-dismiss="modal"]' ).on( 'click', function() {
    var target = this

    $( target ).closest( '.modal' )
        .one( 'hide.bs.modal hidden.bs.modal', function( event ) {
            event.relatedTarget = target
        } )
} )
```

The selector and listener can be further optimized depending on how the modals are used in a project. For example: if you know you're not going to use `hide.bs.modal` you can just modify `hidden.bs.modal`'s event instead.

Comment: This approach doesn't account for when the user clicks the X button, which resides in `.modal-header`, not `.modal-footer`.

Answer (score 1):

The *@JoshCrozier* answer is good and useful but sometimes we need to **Determine witch element triggered the modal to opened/closed AFTER it has been closed.** (*@Nomad* has mentioned to this in the comments below the *@JoshCrozier* answer).

Also some times we need to determine which link or button in the `body` or `header` triggered the modal to close (not just buttons in the `footer`).

**Then** i write this solution to **mix** *@JoshCrozier* **and** *@Katia* **answers with my way and improve the final solution**:

### **Add this part to Scripts of your page:**

```
$('body').on('click','.modal .dismiss-modal', function() {
    var closeRelatedTarget = this;
    var $modal = $(closeRelatedTarget).closest('.modal');
    $modal.one('hide.bs.modal hidden.bs.modal', function(event) {
        $modal.data('closeRelatedTarget',closeRelatedTarget);
    });
    $modal.data('closeRelatedTarget','wait');
    $modal.modal('hide');
});
$('body').on('show.bs.modal','.modal', function(event){
    $(this).data('closeRelatedTarget','anElement');
    $(this).data('showRelatedTarget',event.relatedTarget);
});
```

---

### Now use it easily with simple Event Handlers or Get the target element:

● Determine witch element triggered the modal to ***show* on `show` and `shown`** *(An embed Bootstrap feature)*:

```
 $('#MyModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
     console.log(event.relatedTarget);
 });
```

and

```
 $('#MyModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
     console.log(event.relatedTarget);
 });
```

---

● Determine witch element triggered the modal to ***close* on `hidden`**

```
 $('#BuyModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (event) {
      if($(this).data('closeRelatedTarget')=='wait')
      {return;}
 
      console.log($('#MyModal').data('closeRelatedTarget'));
 });
```

---

● Determine witch element triggered the modal to ***show* even after the modal is closed**

```
 console.log($('#MyModal').data('showRelatedTarget'));
```

---

● Determine witch element triggered the modal to ***close* even after the modal is closed**

```
 console.log($('#MyModal').data('closeRelatedTarget'));
```

---

> **Note:** Instead of `data-dismiss="modal"` property use my `modal-dismiss` class to each element in the model that you can close the model and you want determine it (Don't use both `modal-dismiss` class and `data-dismiss="modal"` together).
>
> **Example:** `<a href="/more_info.html" class="dismiss-modal">More info</a>`
>
> **Why?** Because `data-dismiss="modal"` close the model and trigger hide and hidden before we set `closeRelatedTarget`.

Answer (score 1):

We're overthinking this. It's as simple as a standard button handler. The data-dismiss="modal" will make the dialog go away, and we'll still know that the button that we were interested in was clicked.

```
$('#delete-file-modal').on('click','#delete-file-modal #confirm-delete-button', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('confirmed delete');
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Edited : A solution that works well with BOOTSTRAP 4+ that I haven't seen here, can be adapted with other versions including for v5. May be useful to someone if needed.

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Annuler</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Valider</button>
</div>

$('#prompt_modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
    let buttons = this.querySelectorAll('.btn'); // or others selectors
    buttons.forEach(btn => {
        btn.onclick = () => {
            console.log(btn);
            // do something with btn (textCOntent, dataset, classlist, others) 
            // to detect clicked...
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: But this is not a pure js solution? It's Jquery.

Comment: @SiddharthBhansali It's true !
In fact "(in the bootstrap call function)" was meant to suggest except the bootstrap function call itself. But I take that out...
Let's say that with v5, it's possible...