# Determine which button opened a Bootstrap 3 modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following Bootstrap buttons:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-button="create" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">Create</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-button="delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">Delete</button>
```

and this is the modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

How can I figure out which button triggered the modal to open?

Specifically, I need the `data-button` attribute.

Comment: If you have a different question, please ask a new question. It's not appropriate to add additional questions to an existing question. I have rolled back your last edit.

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie thanks. The answer below answered it. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can listen to either of the `show.bs.modal`/`shown.bs.modal` events.

Within the function, the event has a `relatedTarget` property attached to it. You can use this to determine which button triggered the modal to open.

> [Bootstrap 3 - Modal events:](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)
>
> This event fires immediately when the show instance method is called. If caused by a click, the clicked element is available as the `relatedTarget` property of the event.

```
$('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var $trigger = $(e.relatedTarget);
});
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/07t7yfye/)

.. and if you want to access the `data-button` attribute, use:

```
$(e.relatedTarget).data('button');
```

---

Conversely, if you want to determine which button caused the modal to close, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28270333/how-do-i-know-which-button-is-click-when-bootstrap-modal-closes/28270395#28270395).

Comment: thanks! this is exactly what i was trying to do. I didn't realize there were built in events for this.

Comment: I updated the question how do i add a class to the trigger element? this doesn't work e.relatedTarget.addClass('triggered')

Comment: @narayan It's not working because it's not a jQuery object. Try wrapping it with `$()`... like this: `$(e.relatedTarget).addClass('triggered');`

Comment: Works with Bootstrap 4, too