# send data into codeigniter controller using ajax

Tags: php, ajax

this is my ajax code

```js
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {


    var $modal = $(this);
      var  esseyId = e.relatedTarget.id;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>Moredetails/fetchmonth'',
        data: {EID: esseyId},
        success:function(result) {
            alert(result); // alert your date variable value here
        },
        error:function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });

})
```

I'm trying to pass ID into bootstrap popup model and after that id assign to database query . this is my controller and view code

**controller**

```html
<?php
 function fetchmonth()
    {
    
    $day = $this->input->post('EID');
        if(!empty($day))
        {
            echo $day;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "No Data";
        }
    
    }

?>
```

**view**

```html
<?php

<button id='$row->fldTourRouteID' data-id='.$row->fldProductCabinID.'  data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' class='showiteneray btn btn-default' type='submit'>ITINERARY</button>

?>
<div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-body edit-content">
```

please help me how to i pass this ID into controller using Ajax

Comment: You are almost there - `e.relatedTarget` will give you the button that was clicked.  To get its HTML id, use `$(e.relatedTarget).attr('id')`.  To get its data attributes, use `$(e.relatedTarget).data('id')`.  This is really a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28270333/how-do-i-know-which-button-is-clicked-when-the-bootstrap-modal-closes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I know which button is clicked when the bootstrap modal closes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28270333/how-do-i-know-which-button-is-clicked-when-the-bootstrap-modal-closes)